# Google maps - different marker icon per category

Tags: json, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to give each marker with a different category a different marker image.
In the json i have 3 examples all with different categories (one, two and three).

At the moment i have one marker image being used for all, but i want to use the category value to control the image URL that is used.

I was possibly thinking about having a url variable with a place to insert the category colour (var url = "http://domain.com/images/marker_" + [category] + ".png"). I can then mix that in with a switch statment, but that is as far as i got.

What is the best way for me to handle this?

Here is the JS i have for the Google maps. I am using v3 of the API.

```
(function() {

    window.onload = function() {


    // Creating a new map
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.033591,-36.035156),
        zoom: 3,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });


    // Creating the JSON data
    var json = [
        {
            "title": "USA",
            "lat": 37.616552,
            "lng": -92.988281,
            "description": "<strong>USA</strong> ...",
            "category": "one"
        },
        {
            "title": "France",
            "lat": 48.372793,
            "lng": 1.230469,
            "description": "<strong>France</strong> ...",
            "category": "two"
        },
        {
            "title": "UK",
            "lat": 51.517403,
            "lng": -0.098877,
            "description": "<strong>UK</strong> ...",
            "category": "three"
        }
    ]

    // Custom marker - Need one for each category
    var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
        'http://i.imgur.com/3YJ8z.png',
        new google.maps.Size(19,25),    // size of the image
        new google.maps.Point(0,0) // origin, in this case top-left corner

    );

    // Creating a global infoWindow object that will be reused by all markers
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    // Marker Clusterer setup
    var mcOptions = {
        gridSize: 50,
        maxZoom: 15
    };
    var markers = [];

    // Looping through the JSON data
    for (var i = 0, length = json.length; i < length; i++) {
        var data = json[i],
            latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);

        // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map,
            title: data.title,
            icon: image
        });
        markers.push(marker);


        // Creating a closure to retain the correct data, notice how I pass the current data in the loop into the closure (marker, data)
        (function(marker, data) {

            // Attaching a click event to the current marker
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
                infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });


        })(marker, data);

    }// END for loop

    // Cluster the markers
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);

}// END window.onload

})();
```

Thanks

Comment: [Here is Mike Williams' classic categories map](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_categories.html) from his v2 tutorial (translated to v3).  Solves the issue you are working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@zizther
You want to categorize markers with MarkerClusterer, don't you?
If you so, you can try this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding : 0;
        margin : 0;
      }
      #category_panel {
        background-color : white;
        padding : 1px;
        font-size : 13px;
        margin-top : 5px;
        border : 1px solid #aaa;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function() {

        var clusterer;

        window.onload = function() {

          // Creating a new map
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center : new google.maps.LatLng(30.033591, -36.035156),
            zoom : 3,
            mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            noClear : true
          });

          var selectDiv = $("#category_panel")[0];
          map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(selectDiv);

          // Creating the JSON data
          var json = [{
            "title" : "USA",
            "lat" : 37.616552,
            "lng" : -92.988281,
            "description" : "<strong>USA</strong> ...",
            "category" : "one"
          }, {
            "title" : "France",
            "lat" : 48.372793,
            "lng" : 1.230469,
            "description" : "<strong>France</strong> ...",
            "category" : "two"
          }, {
            "title" : "UK",
            "lat" : 51.517403,
            "lng" : -0.098877,
            "description" : "<strong>UK</strong> ...",
            "category" : "three"
          }];


          /*******
           * for test (start)
           ********/

          var sw = new google.maps.LatLng(37.616552, -92.988281);
          var ne = new google.maps.LatLng(51.517403, -0.098877);
          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(sw, ne);
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
          var lat,lng,category;
          var categories = ["one", "two", "three"];
          for(var i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
            lat = Math.random() * (ne.lat() - sw.lat()) + sw.lat();
            lng = Math.random() * (ne.lng() - sw.lng()) + sw.lng();
            category = categories[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
            json.push({
              "title" : "random #" + i,
              "lat" : lat,
              "lng" : lng,
              "description" : "<strong>" + category + "</strong><br>random #" + i,
              "category" : category
            });
          }
          /*******
           * for test (end)
           ********/


          // Custom marker - Need one for each category
          var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
            'http://i.imgur.com/3YJ8z.png',
            new google.maps.Size(19, 25), // size of the image
            new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // origin, in this case top-left corner
          );

          // Creating a global infoWindow object that will be reused by all markers
          var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

          // Marker Clusterer setup
          var mcOptions = {
            gridSize : 50,
            maxZoom : 15
          };
          clusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, [], mcOptions);

          var markers = {};
          var categoryIcons = {
            "one" : "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=1%7CFF0000%7C000000",
            "two" : "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=2%7C00FFFF%7C000000",
            "three" : "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=3%7CFF00FF%7C000000"
          }

          // Looping through the JSON data
          for (var i = 0, length = json.length; i < length; i++) {
            var data = json[i],
                latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng),
                category = data.category;

            if (category in markers == false) {
              markers[category] = [];
            }

            // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position : latLng,
              title : data.title,
              icon : categoryIcons[data.category]
            });
            markers[category].push(marker);

            // Creating a closure to retain the correct data, notice how I pass the current data in the loop into the closure (marker, data)
            (function(marker, data) {

              // Attaching a click event to the current marker
              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
                infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
              });
            })(marker, data);

          }// END for loop

          $("#category").change(function(){
            var selected = $(this).val();
            clusterer.clearMarkers();
            clusterer.addMarkers(markers[selected]);
          });
          $("#category").change();
        }// END window.onload
      })();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map">
      <div id="category_panel">
        category:<select id="category">
          <option value="one">one</option>
          <option value="two">two</option>
          <option value="three">three</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: How would this work if i wanted to load all markers at the same time but have checkboxes to add and remove markers? I know you can hide and show markers, but i guess markerclusterer does not register they showing or not because they are not actually removed.